# Prove using Rolle's theorem that $x^2$ has $1$ root

Tags: calculus, probability-limit-theorems

I'm having a hard time using Rolle's theorem in this proof and my professor said that it will likely be an exam question similar to the one above.

Comment: Why using Rolle???

Comment: because its in the rolle's section of our textbook

Comment: I think what @Martigan means is: if your question is "Why is there one solution to $x^2 = 0$?", then this seems trivial using basic algebra/postulates of the real number system. Is your question something else?

Comment: You have asked to use Rolle's theorem by your professor and if you use a different approach you won't get a credit for your answer! Stick to what your professor said! Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^2$. Now $f(0) = 0$, and $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0, +\infty)$.
Suppose there is another $a > 0$ such that $f(0) = f(a) = 0$. Then by Rolle's theorem there exists a point $c \in (0, a)$ such that
$$f'(c) = 0,$$
but this is clearly impossible, because as we said earlier $f$ is strictly increasing and therefore $f'(x) > 0$ on $(0, +\infty)$. The same argument can be applied to the interval $(-\infty, 0)$ and we conclude that $0$ is the only root.

Comment: don't know why rolle's theorem is used instead of common sense? +1

Comment: @ADG: Ahah yes, that requirement is a bit too much, it could be done in many simpler ways... Whatever...

Comment: because the question didnt say use common sense it says use rolles Theorem.Thanks Rubik your solution helped :)

Comment: @user212261: Glad I could be of help! Would you accept my answer? (Tick button under the votes buttons.)

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Consider the function $x^2$ over the interval $[-a,a]$

> **Rolle's theorem:** If a real-valued function $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$, differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, and $f(a) = f(b)$, then there exists at least one $c$ in the open interval $(a, b)$ such that
>   $$f'(c) = 0.$$